# AngularJS não lê input do tipo hidden?

Tags: angularjs

Em uma determinada ocasião, estávamos desenvolvendo um formulário aqui na empresa onde, ao selecionar um produto através de um Autocomplete, o ID desse produto era guardando  num `input hidden`.

Reparei que o AngularJS não estava capturando o valor desse input hidden, no qual era necessário para saber o `id` do produto selecionada.

O Autocomplete foi desenvolvido utilizando `jQuery`, que insere o valor no input hidden pelo `val()`.

Assim:

```
$('#produto_id').val($(this).data('id'));
```

No Angular JS temos esse código:

```
 <input type='hidden' ng-model="entrada.produto_id" id="produto_id">
```

Porém ao chamar a função `salvar` com o `ng-submit`, não aparece o valor de `entrada.produto_id`, mas apenas os outros campos.

Descobrimos que era necessário fazer com que o jQuery fizesse um `trigger('input')` ao inserir o valor em `#produto_id`. Porém mesmo assim continuou não funcionando. Mas funcionou tudo corretamente quando substituímos o `hidden` por `text` (com `display:none`);

**Observação**: Primeiramente, antes de fazer a pergunta, gostaria de destacar que o **intuito dessa pergunta não é saber como contornar essa situação**, pois, como citado acima, já resolvemos.

Gostaria apenas de saber se é uma afirmação oficial dizer que o `AngularJS` não lê inputs do tipo hidden.

Comment: Como estava o seu input hidden Wallace?

Comment: @Miguel não tinha aparecido na pergunta, kkkkk. Essa nova edição do Post tá me trolando direto.

Comment: Quando precisei utilizar o tipo hidden, o que resolveu o meu problema foi utilizar um `ng-init`. Exemplo: `<input type='hidden' ng-model="entrada.produto_id" id="produto_id" ng-init="entrada.produto_id = 5" />`

Comment: @CelsomTrindade boa! mas o problema nesse caso é que os dados estão vindo de uma chamada jQuery.

Comment: Será que tinhas de definir o valor no `ng-value` em vez de ser só no value como estavas a fazer com jquery?

Comment: @Miguel o `ng-value` não tem uma "finalidade mágica". Que eu saiba o que ele faz é um "atalho" de `value="{{name}}"` por `ng-value="name"`. Ele não tem outra finalidade além dessa (não que eu saiba, kkk)

Comment: Acabei refazendo minha resposta pois, após alguns testes, notei que o comportamento mudou - e muito! Agora a resposta final está de acordo com a versão mais recente de AngularJs e, espero eu, que consiga esclarecer bem sua dúvida! =D

Comment: Qual é o motivo do negativo? pode explicar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lendo mais do assunto e fazendo alguns testes, observei que esse é o comportamento "esperado" do `AngularJs` quando relacionado ao campo `input` e formulários em geral.

Nas versões mais antigas, isso acontecia devido ao princípio de `Two-Way DataBinding` ou seja, a comunicação em 2 vias. Quando o usuário alterar o valor no input, o mesmo é propagado automaticamente para o controlador.

Como o campo `hidden` nunca será editado (pelo menos é o que esperamos) não há necessidade de se ter `Two-Way DataBinding`, apenas a definição inicial de seu valor.

---

Nas versões mais recentes de `AngularJs` (Testado a partir da versão 1.5), o comportamento é um pouco diferente. O que determina se um "campo" existe ou não dentro de um formulário - aos "olhos" do `AngularJs` - é a declaração de `name` e `ngModel`, ou seja, se não houver esses 2 atributos, o campo simplesmente "não existe" e, portanto, não é possível obter o seu valor (ao menos não pelo modo tradicional).

Já com a declaração desses atributos, independente de como e quando o seu valor é declarado/definido sempre foi possível ler o seu valor ao utilizar o método tradicional de envio de formulários do `AngularJS` - `ngSubmit`.

Veja esse exemplo: https://plnkr.co/edit/qsxDbTPbX4km3c9skEAz?p=preview

---

**Por que sua versão não funciona?**

Em nenhum momento o valor que você deseja passar ao campo foi enviado pelo meio `AngularJs`, ou seja, não foi aplicado ao seu `ngModel`. Quando nós, usuários, interagimos com o campo que possui `ngModel`, o mesmo automaticamente atualiza o seu `value`, logo, o valor é atualizado.

No entanto, o inverso não acontece. Quando atualizamos o valor de `value`, o mesmo não é passado para o `ngModel`, [veja esse exemplo aqui](https://plnkr.co/edit/YrCLORikwflnHX5iBEgH?p=preview). Se você clicar no botão para declarar o valor automaticamente e em seguida enviar o formulário, o `alert` é `undefined`. No entanto, se você apenas adicionar 1 caracter e enviar o formulário novamente, o `alert` já irá exibir o valor correto.

---

Diferente das versões anteriores, onde era necessário algumas "arte manhas" para poder contornar essa situação, como por exemplo:

- Usar o `ngInit`;
- Usar `value` ou `ngValue`;
- Esconder o `input` com uma `class` ou `style`;
- Outros métodos mais 'manuais', etc..

Tudo que precisamos fazer é:

- Declarar os atributos `name` e `ngModel`;
- Atribuir o valor ao `ngModel` e não ao seu `value`;

> Nota: Aqui não será possível fazer essa declaração utilizando jQuery. Você precisaria mesclar os dois para obter o resultado final. Não cheguei a testar, mas seria algo assim:

```
var novoValor = jQuery(this).data('id'); //Note que dentro de uma função AngularJs a chamada de jQuery por '$' não funciona, devemos usar a declaração jQuery
$scope.valorHidden = novoValor;
```

---

Resumindo: O campo `hidden` dentro de `AngularJs` funciona. Basta fazer a declaração correta de modo que o mesmo seja reconhecido como um elemento válido "aos olhos" do nosso querido `Angular`.

Comment: Olá, Celsom. Vi que vc deletou a anterior e postou uma nova versão da resposta. Lembre-se que nesses casos você pode editar a que foi deletada com a versão mais nova, e em seguida restaurá-la. Pode ser mais interessante em casos de "mudança de idéia", ainda mais considerando que as deletadas apenas ficam mais "discretas" na postagem (usuários com reputação mais alta enxergam elas no fim da lista e em cor diferente).

Comment: @Bacco sim sim, mas eu deletei pois após alguns testes vi que ela possui muitas informações desatualizadas, então optei por uma nova, já que havia uma grande diferença de informações.